# What are test case enumeration.? How to write it.?

Tags: manual-testing

Recently, while looking for a job change on manual QA, I had interviewed on regular testing concepts questions. But,  in a few companies,they gave some scenario and asked to write test case enumerations for it. Is it like test steps I need to write.? As per my knowledge, enumeration means complete, ordered list of all the items in a collection, so, is it writing all the test steps with description.?

Comment: Quite ambiguous- why not ask the person who set the question to explain what they mean?

Comment: Actually, I have written test steps and the interviewer didn't reply any negative answer as if it is correct procedure he moved on to further questions. However, I didn't get select in to those companies, so not sure where did I miss it. In-order to  make clear my doubts, I put this question here. Sorry but if it is not clear

Comment: Please provide some examples, like what the scenarios you faced in interview.?

Answer (score 1):

Listing all possible test case names which could be extracted out of the scenario provided and classifying them in terms of priority and positive/negative/types is test case enumeration.
Kindly comment if you need anything, here is an example for better understanding.
Enumerate test cases for Login:(Classifying priorities into P1>P2>P3)
Positive cases include:

1. P1-Verify the login dialog box
2. P1-Verify the login id
3. P1-Verify the password
4. P1-Verify the submit button

Negative cases include:
 1. P3-Verify logging in with empty id and password fields

Note: Haven't covered all the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Test Enumeration orders those scripts one by one- like 1,2,3... etc present in the test suite.It is just like defining the priority with which you want to run a specific script in a test suite.

Answer (score 0):

For me enumeration means give for each test case identifier which is no 1, 2, 3 etc but which can tell you something, for example in very simple project you have three modules Users, Orders, Reports you can enumerate your use cases User.Accounts.1, User.Accounts.2..., User.Roles.1, User.Roles.2, Orders.Add.1, Orders.Edit.1, Orders.Edit.2, etc.
I gave long identifiers but you can short it or even replace names by numbers.
Other way (which is even much clear) you can gave names to use cases:

```
User.Accounts.Add account
User.Accounts.Edit account
User.Accounts.Remove account
User.Accounts.Remove account - negative (cannot remove)
User.Roles.Add role
etc...
```

This helps you (and others) to see if list of test cases you planned is full or you should add some new.